# rsync over SSH preserve ownership only for www-data owned files

Tags: linux, ssh, webserver, rsync

I am using rsync to replicate a web folder structure from a local server to a remote server.  Both servers are ubuntu linux.  I use the following command, and it works well:

```
rsync -az /var/www/ user@10.1.1.1:/var/www/
```

The usernames for the local system and the remote system are different.  From what I have read it may not be possible to preserve all file and folder owners and groups.  That is OK, but I would like to preserve owners and groups just for the www-data user, which does exist on both servers.

Is this possible?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

** EDIT **

There is some mention of rsync being able to preserve ownership and groups on remote file syncs here: http://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2005-August/013203.html

** EDIT 2 **

I ended up getting the desired affect thanks to many of the helpful comments and answers here.  Assuming the IP of the source machine is 10.1.1.2 and the IP of the destination machine is 10.1.1.1.  I can use this line from the destination machine:

```
sudo rsync -az user@10.1.1.2:/var/www/ /var/www/
```

This preserves the ownership and groups of the files that have a common user name, like www-data. Note that using `rsync` without `sudo` does not preserve these permissions.

Comment: You probably shouldn't make your root usernames different from "root".  That's a default that many things assume will be consistent, because it's ALWAYS the same on every unix or linux system, and has been for decades.  If your root username is not "root", then even if things work for now, expect something to fail in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the user names I am referring to above are users with sudo privileges, not the "root" users.  Of course there are still root accounts that I choose not to use in general.  I hope I can do what i need to do with just sudo.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're preserving a specific owner:group across the transfer, or preserving *all* owner:group settings? As non-root, I could transfer files but they always ended up being owned by the non-root user that rsync was set to. As root, all owner:groups were preserved fine, I just didn't want to run rsync (really lsyncd) as root

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also sudo the rsync on the target host by using the `--rsync-path` option:

```
# rsync -av --rsync-path="sudo rsync" /path/to/files user@targethost:/path
```

This lets you authenticate as `user` on targethost, but still get privileged write permission through `sudo`.  You'll have to modify your sudoers file on the target host to avoid sudo's request for your password.  `man sudoers` or run `sudo visudo` for instructions and samples.

You mention that you'd like to retain the ownership of files owned by www-data, but not other files.  If this is really true, then you may be out of luck unless you implement `chown` or a second run of `rsync` to update permissions.  There is no way to tell rsync to preserve ownership for *just one user*.

That said, you should read about rsync's `--files-from` option.

```
rsync -av /path/to/files user@targethost:/path
find /path/to/files -user www-data -print | \
  rsync -av --files-from=- --rsync-path="sudo rsync" /path/to/files user@targethost:/path
```

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure exactly how piping find's output into `--files-from=-` will work.  You'll undoubtedly need to experiment.

Comment: This all does make a lot of sense, but I try exactly this with `--chown=user:group` option, and it doesn't work. Adding `--super` doens't help either. I wonder if using `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` is somehow incompatible with `--chown`. I haven't tried using the root user directly for ssh, but I generally prefer to sudo from another user account.

Comment: I found the answer: it seems `--chown` doesn't work unless you also set `--owner --group`. It's kind of counter intuitive, since the latter options talk about perserving owner and group from source. On top of that, the man page for `--chown` does not mention that, neither is a warning issued. The section for `--usermap` does mention this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot `chown` files to somebody else than you, if you are not root. So you would have to `rsync` using the `www-data` account, as all files will be created with the specified user as owner. So you need to `chown` the files afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Yes i wanted to avoid writing a script to chown them after, because i want this is all be automated in a script .sh file.  I don't really want to save the password in the .sh file.

Comment: You should never save passwords in any file on your server if you can avoid it.  As Graham outlined below, use SSH keys.  Also, xato and Graham are entirely correct - only root can set the username on a file being written.  If you want to preserve ownership, you **must** run rsync as root.

Comment: @ghoti - yes I use SSH keys, they are great, but they are not enough if you want to do something like `sudo chown www-data file.html` over the ssh.  You still have to re-enter the sudo password.  So i will have to make the script run from the destination machine, as suggested in some of the other answers.  If I run the script with sudo permissions, it should work.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind ... I think you may have missed my answer here regarding the `--rsync-path` option.  You can sudo the target rsync even if you run the command from the source server.  You will need to modify your sudoers file to avoid sudo's password request of course.

Answer (score 3):

> The root users for the local system and the remote system are different.

What does this mean?  The *root* user is uid 0.  How are they different?

Any user with read permission to the directories you want to copy can determine what usernames own what files.  Only root can change the ownership of files being *written*.

You're currently running the command on the source machine, which restricts your writes to the permissions associated with user@10.1.1.1.  Instead, you can try to run the command *as root* on the *target* machine.  Your *read* access on the source machine isn't an issue.

So on the target machine (10.1.1.1), assuming the source is 10.1.1.2:

```
# rsync -az user@10.1.1.2:/var/www/ /var/www/
```

Make sure your groups match on both machines.

Also, set up access to user@10.1.1.2 using a DSA or RSA key, so that you can avoid having passwords floating around.  For example, as root on your target machine, run:

```
# ssh-keygen -d
```

Then take the contents of the file `/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` and add it to `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the source machine.  You can `ssh user@10.1.1.2` as root from the target machine to see if it works.  If you get a password prompt, check your error log to see why the key isn't working.

Comment: the usernames are different.  I am the user on both.  I will try this, thanks.

Comment: that didn't work either.  The syncing of the files worked, but the owner and group of the files on the destination machine are still just the username that executed the rsync.  Even when I use the `-o` option.

Comment: As I said, above, only root can set usernames on files that it writes.  So if you want to set usernames, run rsync as `root`.  As you can see from the rsync man page, the `-o` option is for "super-user only".  That's root.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and cheated the rsync command,

rsync -avz --delete root@x.x.x.x:/home//domains/site/public_html/ /home/domains2/public_html && chown -R wwwusr:wwwgrp /home/domains2/public_html/

the && runs the chown against the folder when the rsync completes successfully (1x '&' would run the chown regardless of the rsync completion status)

Comment: (1x '&' would run the chown regardless of the rsync completion status)

That would actually background the rsync and cause the chown to run before the rsync finished.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could skip the challenges of rsync altogether, and just do this through a tar tunnel.

```
sudo tar zcf - /path/to/files | \
  ssh user@remotehost "cd /some/path; sudo tar zxf -"
```

You'll need to set up your SSH keys as Graham described.

Note that this handles full directory copies, not incremental updates like rsync.

The idea here is that:

- you tar up your directory,
- instead of creating a tar file, you send the tar output to stdout,
- that stdout is piped through an SSH command to a *receiving* tar on the other host,
- but that receiving tar is run by sudo, so it has privileged write access to set usernames.

Comment: Yeah, but this way you lose the chance to do incremental backups. For any changes in the source, you will have to upload the whole stuff every single time. Pretty much inefficient.

Comment: Yup.  As you can see, I noted that in this answer.  The OP didn't mention *why* he/she was using rsync.  Some folks use it for incremental updates, some use it for one-time copies when they want to make sure the permissions match.  If incremental updates are your priority, then this is not the answer for you.  It is, however, worth noting as a possible solution to other problems.

Answer (score -1):

## rsync version 3.1.2

I mostly use windows in local, so this is the command line i use to sync files with the server (debian) :

```
user@user-PC /cygdrive/c/wamp64/www/projects

$ rsync -rptgoDvhP --chown=www-data:www-data --exclude=.env --exclude=vendor --exclude=node_modules --exclude=.git --exclude=tests --exclude=.phpintel --exclude=storage ./website/ username@hostname:/var/www/html/website
```