# How to copy only symbolic links through rsync

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, symlink

How do I copy symbolic links only (and not the file it points to) or other files using rsync?

I tried

`rsync -uvrl input_dir output_dir`

but I need to exclusively copy the symbolic links only ?

any trick using include exclude options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [this question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586798/rsync-over-ssh-preserve-ownership-only-for-www-data-owned-files/9590132#9590132), you can script this as a pipe.  Pipes are an integral part of shell programming and shell scripting.

```
find /path/to/files -type l -print | \
  rsync -av --files-from=- /path/to/files user@targethost:/path
```

**What's going on here?**

The `find` command starts at /path/to/files and steps recursively through everything "under" that point.  The options to `find` are conditions that limit what gets output by the `-print` option.  In this case, only things of `-type l` (symbolic link, according to `man find`) will be printed to find's "standard output".

These files become the "standard input" of the `rsync` command's `--file-from` option.

Give it a shot.  I haven't actually *tested* this, but it seems to me that it should work.

Comment: This won't copy the symlinks as symlinks, though.

Comment: @Dan ... Well, `-a` translates to `-rlptgoD`, and `-l` is documented to, "when symlinks are encountered, recreate the symlink on the destination." What results did you encounter?

Comment: Oh! I missed that -a includes -l!

Answer (score 6):

You can generate a list of files excluding links with `find input_dir -not -type l`, rsync has an option `--exclude-from=exlude_file.txt`

you can do it in two steps :

`find input_dir -not -type l > /tmp/rsync-exclude.txt`

`rsync -uvrl --exclude-from=/tmp/rsync-exclude.txt input_dir output_dir`

one line bash :

`rsync -urvl --exclude-from=<(find input_dir -not -type l | sed 's/^..//') input_dir output_dir`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it more easily like:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type l -exec rsync -avP {} ssh_server:/path/to/server/ \;
```

EDIT:
If you want to copy symbolic links of the current directory only without making it recursive. You can do:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec rsync -avP {} ssh_server:/path/to/server/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this:

```
find ./ -type l -print > /tmp/list_of_links.txt
rsync -av --files-from=/tmp/list_of_links.txt /path/to/files user@targethost:/path
```

The reason is simple. In the previous suggested version, I had to enter my password with every file. This way I can send all symlinks at once, with just one password entered.