# rsync ownership between mac OS X and linux

Tags: linux, macos, rsync, ownership

I want to use rsync to upload a local web application on my OS X machine to a linux server.

I use this command :

```
sudo rsync -Harov --delete -e "ssh -p 33224" "/Users/me/myapp/" "linuxuser@12.34.56.78:/home/linuxuser/test-rsync-app"
```

The problem is that my local application has some folders that belongs to _www (on Mac OS X), 
and when uploaded, they all belong to linuxuser, so I lose the ownership of the apache user for those folders.

Ideally, I would use rsync and the files that belongs to _www on my Mac would belong to www-data on the linux server.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have root privileges on the Linux server then no, you cannot make the user (and group) be www-data.

If you do have root privileges, this question should be helpful to you:

[rsync over SSH preserve ownership only for www-data owned files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586798/rsync-over-ssh-preserve-ownership-only-for-www-data-owned-files)